# NVARCHAR TO DATETIME conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a parameter that has a value of `14-Sep-2012 15:47:27` that I would like to update a table column with which is in `2012-08-10 05:00:00.000` format.

What would be the query needed '

```
@UpdateTime = '14-Sep-2012 15:47:27'

Update tbl 
Set Datetimecol = CONVERT(datetime,@UpdateTime,110) ??
```

I am using SQL Server 2008. Thank you !

Comment: What's the problem that you're having?

Comment: Why 'Sept' not 'Sep'? Is March 'Marc' or do you have a full list of the Month portion?

Comment: It is just a simple NVARCHAR to Datetime . My variable is in nvarchar format where at the column I need to update in the table is in datetime format . the conversion code is I think 110 for this . I have revised the question again . Please help !

Comment: evry thing is right : please remove 110 from query :              select DATEADD(day,2,CONVERT(datetime,'14-Sep-2012 15:47:27'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your language settings are always English and your regional settings don't change, here is another approach (along with sample data of various potential formats):

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(y NVARCHAR(15));

INSERT @x VALUES('18-Sept-2012'),('9-May-2012'),('19-Oct-2012'),('04-March-2012');

SELECT z, CONVERT(DATETIME,z) FROM
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(y,s+1,3) + ' ' + LEFT(y,s-1) + ', ' + RIGHT(y,4) FROM
  (
    SELECT y, CHARINDEX('-',y) FROM @x
  ) AS y(y,s)
) AS z(z);
```

Results:

```
Sep 18, 2012   2012-09-18 00:00:00.000
May 9, 2012    2012-05-09 00:00:00.000
Oct 19, 2012   2012-10-19 00:00:00.000
Mar 04, 2012   2012-03-04 00:00:00.000
```

You can use the same calculation for a variable:

```
DECLARE 
  @y NVARCHAR(15) = N'18-Sept-2012',
  @z DATETIME;

SELECT @z = CONVERT(DATETIME,z) FROM
(
  SELECT SUBSTRING(y,s+1,3) + ' ' + LEFT(y,s-1) + ', ' + RIGHT(y,4) FROM
  (
    SELECT @y, CHARINDEX('-',@y)
  ) AS y(y,s)
) AS z(z);

SELECT @z;
-- UPDATE ...
```

(Now try with `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;` and watch it all go to, well, somewhere.)

For this reason I highly recommend you stop storing / passing dates using the `nvarchar` type. We have strongly typed date/time types for a reason. When you need to pass a string literal, you should be using unambiguous, standard formats that aren't prone to differences in language, regional and dateformat settings. In this case the right format should be `YYYYMMDD`:

```
20120918
```

For more info, see:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 3):

For the edited question, you only need to drop the `110` specification. There really isn't a specification for the format you have shown, but English installations of SQL Server will convert it.

e.g.

```
declare @UpdateTime datetime = '14-Sep-2012 15:47:27'
select CONVERT(datetime,@UpdateTime)

-- result
September, 14 2012 15:47:27
```

---

Assuming your month portion is at least 3 characters long, e.g. Mar, Marc, March, Sept, you can convert that very bad text datetime to a normal 3-char month format using the following

```
declare @updatetime nvarchar(20) = '18-Sept-2012'
declare @fixedtime nvarchar(20)
set @fixedtime = stuff(@updatetime,1,charindex('-',@updatetime),'')
set @fixedtime = Left(@updatetime,charindex('-',@updatetime))
               + stuff(@fixedtime,4,len(@fixedtime)-8,'')

-- @fixedtime contains `18-Sep-2012`

Update tbl 
Set Datetimecol = @fixedtime
```

Yes, I deliberately left out the CAST/CONVERT in the update statement.

Comment: It is just a simple NVARCHAR to Datetime . My variable is in nvarchar format where at the column I need to update in the table is in datetime format . the conversion code is I think 110 for this . I have revised the question again . Please help !